# POST not working after rewrite .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, post, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

My forms not working after adding rewrite to .htaccess. I found many topics with similar problem but neither have solution to my issue.
I would be grateful if you could take a look.
There it is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

and here is my post code:)

```
<?php
function send_email ($to_email, $from_email, $from_name, $subject, $msg,
$showinfo) {
//split up to email array, if given
if (is_array($to_email)) {
    $to_email_string = implode(', ', $to_email);
}
else {
    $to_email_string = $to_email;
}

// build content

$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;"  
cellpadding="10">';
$message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Imie i nazwisko:  
</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags( $from_name ) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>E-mail:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags( 
$from_email ) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Temat:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags( 
$subject ) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Wiadomość:</strong> </td><td>" . nl2br( 
strip_tags( $msg ) ) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "</table>";
$message .= "</body></html>";



//Assemble headers
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $from_name <$from_email>" . "\r\n";

//send via PHP's mail() function
if( $showinfo )
{
    mail($to_email_string, $subject, $message, $headers) or die(json_encode(
array( 'error' => true, 'msg' => 'Fel när du skickar meddelanden.')));
    echo json_encode( array( 'error' => false, 'msg' => "Ditt meddelande har
skickats."));
} else {
    mail($to_email_string, $subject, $message, $headers);
}



}


if( isset( $_POST['name']) && isset( $_POST['email']) && isset(   
$_POST['subject']) && isset( $_POST['message']) && $_POST['other'] == '')
{

send_email( "myemail", $_POST['email'], $_POST['name'], 
$_POST['subject'], $_POST['message'], true );
send_email( $_POST['email'], 'myemail', "LHI", 'Copy: ' .
   $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message'], false );
}

if( isset( $_POST['info']) && $_POST['info'] == 'notajax' )
{
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: http://localhost/dash/"); 
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to remove the .php in

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
```

Is there any error message when you load the page?

Comment: I tried, still bad. There is my site www.lhi.nu/contact  There are a lot of errors while loading page but not related to my issue:/

Answer (score 0):

Add this above all your rewriting conditions.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

So your .htaccess will be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Hope this helps!